# How to get iOS AddressBook contact's facebook-synced photo?

Tags: ios, facebook, abaddressbook

I want to get a contact's image from iOS AddressBook with:

```
NSData *contactImageData = ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
```

This works fine for local images but not for images synced with Facebook. 
How can I get these images? Do I have to load them manually from Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the *linked contacts* using `ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople()` — one of these will be the contact that was synced from Facebook, and you can get the image from that.

Unfortunately I am not aware of any way to determine *which one* of the linked contacts is from Facebook, so there's no reliable way to specifically get the Facebook contact image — you just have to get the first image you find, or whatever makes sense in your particular case.